# Peer-reviewer asks the author for the manuscript to be reviewed by two other experts

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have received a peer-reviewer's comment that states that my manuscript needs to be reviewed by experts on two different fields. Is it possible that I am being asked to find those two experts myself and ask them to review my manuscript, or is this probably a mistake/missunderstanding (that is, maybe that comment was not meant to be sent to the manuscript's author)?

Comment: What does the editor say? Have you ask the editor?

Comment: I have sent an ad hoc email asking about that.last Monday. No answer yet.. The decision is "minor revison" but then the reviewer's comment is "need to be reviewed by two other experts". And I also would not know of any of those two experts to whom I could ask to review my manuscript. I hope the manuscript is not reject because of this!

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the actual text, I would guess you are mistaken or the review has a confusing grammatical mistake.  The peer reviewer normally addresses the review to the editor, not the author.  The reviewer is telling the editor that they should select other reviewers.  It is possible that the editor has already done this.  (Did you receive more than one review?)  Probably there is no need for you to do anything.

Comment: The reviewer's comment that was sent to me (the author,) was: This manuscript needs to be reviewed by an expert in X and by an expert in Y.. To me, this comment looks like a comment which was intended to be sent to the editor. It is impossible that they are asking me to find such two experts and ask them to review or support by manuscript, right?...There was only one reviewer.

Comment: Yes, these things are handled by the editor and not the author. Remember the editor has every right to ignore this request as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. Now I feel more confortable with writing to the editor about this.